# Calculate Taylor Polynom

Tags: calculus

Calculate Taylor Polynom of $f(x)=\cos \left( \left(x-4\right)^5 \right)$ at $x_0=4$ in order $n=10$

How should I approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

$\cos t = 1 - \frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}-\frac{t^6}{6!}+ ...$

Now substitutions $t = (x-4)^5$

Comment: So as a series it is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{10} \frac{(x-4)^{10n}}{2n!}$ ?

Comment: No, the series is  $\cos (x-4)^5 = 1 - \frac{(x-4)^{10}}{2!}$ (in the order of 10)

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{10} \frac{(-1)^{n}(x-4)^{10n}}{2n!}$ ?

Comment: NO! Look 

> Blockquote http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%5Ccos+%28%28x-4%29%5E5%29+point+x%3D4+order+10